# capture the output of android command in perl

Tags: perl

root@android:/mnt/sdcard # input keyevent 66I'm running a perl script on android prompt. Wanted to know how do i capture output of a android command to a perl variable. I've done the following, but output is not captured. Please help.

```
use Net::Telnet;
$ip='xx.xxx.xx.xx';
$ip_port='10009';
$port  = Net::Telnet->new( Host=>$ip,Port=>$ip_port,Dump_log=> "dump.log");

@lnes= $port->cmd("input keyevent 66");
        sleep(5);
        $lc=0;
        print "Console Log:";
        while($lc<5)
        {
            print $lnes[$lc];
            print FILE $lnes[$lc];
            ++$lc; 
        }
```

I"m getting only "root@android:/mnt/sdcard # input keyevent 66" only and not the messages displayed after i enter this command. Please help.

Comment: how is `$port` created?

Comment: that cannot be the entire script

Comment: I"ve edited to add port definition.

Comment: What happens if you use the `telnet` utility to that address/port, and enter the same command?

Answer (score 1):

That should be either

```
$port = new Net::Telnet(Host => $ip, Port => $ip_port, Dump_log => "dump.log");
```

or, preferably

```
$port = Net::Telnet->new(Host => $ip, Port => $ip_port, Dump_log => "dump.log");
```

Comment: Ok i've changed it to second one you have suggested. But it was working with the command i've given. Now, how do i solve the original issue?